# Duplicating partial rows using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data that has been imported from elsewhere. the sheet as you see can be solved mainly by moving the data from F and G up a single row, the problem comes where I need on row 10 through 13, which will be after the data has been moved up one will be 10 through 12. I need to have it where the data on 9 through cells A through D copy down till the end of row F. Then continue down and do the same if any other rows have the same "problem"...

I hope I am being clear, if not please ask, but can someone help me here? I thought about using the concept of till the end copy, but I can see that not working because not all cells need it... it only needs to happen when the opportunity arises.

Attached a link to the sheet in hopes to clarify the problem.

[Link to Workbook here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/Imported.xlsx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this code with the data you provided. Should be good, based on data in worksheet. Of course, may need slight adjustments if data scope changes.

```
Sub clean_data()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Imported Data")

With wks

    'first bring columns F:G up to match their line
    For Each cel In Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1), .Columns(6))

        If cel = vbNullString And cel.Offset(, -2) <> vbNullString Then
            .Range(cel.Offset(1), cel.Offset(1, 1)).Copy cel
            cel.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

    Next

    'now fil columns A:D to match PO Date and PO#
    For Each cel In Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1), .Columns(1))

        If cel = vbNullString And cel.Offset(, 5) <> vbNullString Then
            .Range(cel.Offset(-1), cel.Offset(-1, 3)).Copy cel
        End If

    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: They work perfectly thanks a lot, you did much more than I was expecting. I love the simplicity of this code.

Comment: simplicity in code is good. as you grow in coding you will learn how to write simple code that catches a lot of common mistakes or errors.

Comment: I agree 100% I just wish more people would follow that thought process.

Comment: as the saying goes, "can't transmit what you don't have"

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want:

```
Sub CleanUpImport()
    Dim LastCleanUpRow as Long
    Dim FirstSORow as Long
    Dim LastSORow
    Dim TitleRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    LastCleanUpRow = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    TitleRow = 1
    If Range("A1").Value = "" Then
        TitleRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    End If

    ' Delete cells to line up columns F and G
    If Range("F3").Value = "" And Range("G3").Value = "" Then
        Range("F3:G3").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If

    ' Set rows for first SO
    LastSORow = LastCleanUpRow
    FirstSORow = LastSORow
    If Range("F" & LastSORow).Offset(-1).Value <> "" Then
        FirstSORow = Range("F" & LastCleanUpRow).End(xlUp).Row
    End If

    ' Copy SO header to any SOs that have multiple POs
    Do Until FirstSORow = TitleRow

        Range("A" & FirstSORow & ":D" & FirstSORow).Copy Range("A" & FirstSORow & ":D" & LastSORow)
        LastSORow = Range("F" & FirstSORow).End(xlUp).Row
        FirstSORow = LastSORow
        If Range("F" & LastSORow).Offset(-1).Value <> "" Then
            FirstSORow = Range("F" & LastSORow).End(xlUp).Row
            If FirstSORow = TitleRow Then FirstSORow = FirstSORow + 1
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```